# Concavity of continuous positive functions with extra properties

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous positive function and it is not constant. Moreover satisfies the following $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)x')\geq \lambda^4f(x)+(1-\lambda)^4f(x')\,\,\,\,    $$
$\forall\lambda\in[0,1]$ and for all $x,y$.

Does it follow that $f$ has a unique maximum?

Comment: To answer your second question: the maximum does not need to be unique, consider $f(x) \equiv 1$.

Comment: Good point.in my case the function is not constant.

Comment: Concave and positive (and defined on all $\mathbb R$) together imply constant, so something is a little fishy here.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: you Suppose that $f$ has max?  or you have also to ^prove that  ?

Comment: Lets assume that it has atleast one max.

Comment: Then if you have two maxs $x$ and  $x'$ and $x \neq  x'$, with  $f(x)=f(x')=maximum$, then with the above  inequality $$ f(\lambda  x +(1-\lambda)x') \geq f(x)$$  i .e  for  $y=\lambda  x +(1-\lambda)x' $  and  $f(y) \geq  f(x)$,  and this contradicts the maximality of  $x$

Comment: why is that $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)x')\geq f(x)$ ?